# How to show an hidden div if a required field is highlighted?

Tags: javascript, html, hidden, required

for a series of circumstances I need to update an old ASP classic site.
My users need to fill one form that is divided in two `divs` that they can activate (display) clicking on a button.

Instead of doing complicate checks I found useful the `required` attribute of HTML 5 but unfortunately I have some problem when the required field is in the hidden part of the form.

If the user submits the form and the required field (not filled) is located in the hidden `div` the browser displays the alert but, obviously, not the field (because is in the hidden `div`).

Is it possible to automatically show the hidden part of the form in which the `required` field is located?

Some code on the fly:

```html
<form action="anagraphic.asp" method="post">
    <div id="divName" style="display:inline">
        Name <input id="inputName" name="inputName" type="text" required /> 
        <input name="Button1" type="button" value="Next"   
            onclick="document.getElementById('divName').style.display='none';document.getElementById('divSurname').style.display='inline';"/>
    </div>
    <div id="divSurname"style="display:none">
        <input name="Button2" type="button" value="Previous" 
            onclick="document.getElementById('divSurname').style.display='none';document.getElementById('divName').style.display='inline';" />
        Surname <input  id="inputSurname" name="inputSurname" type="text" required  />
        <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>

</form>
```

Let's say that you "forget" to fill the *name* field and you click on *Next*.
You fill surname and you submit the form: immediately the embedded alert appears. Substantially I would like to intercept the event that highlights the required field and at the same time show the first `div` the one with the name.

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you share some code to help explain the problem?

Comment: maybe js to unhide on the onsubmit event ?

Comment: I don't think this is a job for classic asp, as it is a server side technology, and what you appear to want to do is to alter the way your form is displayed before it is submitted.  I'd guess jQuery might offer a solution and I suggest you add that tag to your question

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery when the submit button is clicked to show any required fields that are not visible:

```
function foo()
{
  $("input[required]:hidden").parent().show()
}
```

And let the submit button call the function when clicked:

```
<input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" onclick=foo()/>
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler logic will be if you check the *name* field onclick of Button1. If the *name* field is valid you can hide that and show the *surname* field. This will avoid showing already hidden name field, which breaks the ui flow and may be confusing for the user.